# Android scrollview to scroll up automatically when available space fill so as to show last item

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I dynamically add the views in the scroll view and I want the scroll view to auto scroll up so as to show last items when available space completely fill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is working, but I have also found the following code:

```
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.sscroll);
scrollView .fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

Comment: I think your answer is faster than ours. The `FOCUS_DOWN`or `FOCUS_UP` will return immediatly the bottom or top of the view without calculate the height. Nice! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with [`smoothScrollTo(int x, int y)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#smoothScrollTo%28int,%20int%29) method. It allows 2 parameters:

> **x:** the position where to scroll on the X axis
>   **y:** the position where to scroll on the Y axis

Then, using the `y` parameter, you will be able to autoscroll the `ScrollView` when you'll calculate the height of the first child container (generally `LinearLayout`). Or you can use, as *@KieronPapps* said, the `getTop()` method to retrieve the value of top position of this view relative to its parent *(in pixels)*.

However, to autoscroll directly at the start of the `Activity`, the `getTop()` will return `null` because the UI has not the time to be displayed. Then, to avoid the `null` value, in an `Activity`, you will need to do your autoscroll inside [`onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.Callback.html#onWindowFocusChanged%28boolean%29) as follows:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if(hasFocus){
        // do smoothScrollTo(...);
    }
}
```

Inside a `Fragment` a simple `Runnable` will do the same. I have written [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23001821/2668136) on a similar behaviour, it might help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell the scroll view to scroll to a specific place using `scrollTo(x,y)`. However you want to make sure you don't do it on the main thread since the main thread does its operations in order. So that means sometimes you'll have to wait. Therefore you can do it in a background thread.

```
view.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         scrollView.scrollTo(0, view.getTop());
    }
};
```